# extract variable from macro block

Tags: c++, variables, macros

I am trying to write a function that behaves differently depending on the OS.

I got this code somewhere in my function:

```
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    int cols;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    cols = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
    #else
        int cols;
        #ifdef TIOCGSIZE
        struct ttysize ts;
        ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGSIZE, &ts);
        cols = ts.ts_cols;
        #elif defined(TIOCGWINSZ)
        struct winsize ts;
        ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ts);
        cols = ts.ws_col;
        #endif // TIOCGSIZE
    #endif // OS_WINDOWS
```

So, I want to get the number of columns, but that needs to be done in two different ways for Windows and Linux... I then want to continue working with the `cols` variable. But I get `variable 'cols' is uninitialized when used here`

How can I "extract" the cols variable from the macro block?

Comment: `clos`, `cols`, or `columns`? You need to make sure you are referring to the correct variable *and* that it is declared the same in all parts of the macro *or* thay you declare it before the macro block. (Note: there is no additional scope added by what you show here, so any variable declared that is part of a "selected" block is visible outside of the macro).

Comment: fixed it. But that was not the problem. And the clos-thing was just a typo in my post :)

Comment: The problem is still in my previous comment: you only declare `cols` in the first block, which will not exist if not on Windows. Instead, you need to declare `cols` before *or* actually declare it in the other two blocks.

Comment: ah, I see. Edited. Now I am getting a warning, that cols is uninitialized though.

Comment: Could be because both `TIOCGSIZE` and `TIOCGWINSZ` are undefined.  What do want to do in that case?

Comment: Is that because of my system or due to the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

What the compiler sees on Windows

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
int cols; //This is the only place where `cols` is delcared!
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
cols = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
```

What the compiler sees *not* on Windows

```
    struct ttysize ts;
    ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGSIZE, &ts);
    cols = ts.ts_cols; //cols is not declared
```

or

```
    struct winsize ts;
    ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ts);
    cols = ts.ws_col; //cols is not declared
```

Note that there is no *declaration* of `cols` in the non-Windows code.

A simple solution would be to move the decalration of `cols` before the macro block.

```
int cols = 0; //or -1 or some other error value
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
//...
```

As a note on preprocessor macros:
The preprocessor runs *before* the code is compiled, dealing with `#include`, `#define` (replaces text), `#ifdef` (conditionally includes blocks of code), and so on. Editors and IDEs may show non-use blocks grayed out, but you can also get the preprocessor output seperately to look at (compiler flags depend on your compiler), and this may help you find why this is having errors.

Comment: Some hints explaining the text processing nature of CPP would be a good improvement of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with OS specific behavior, you'll notice that code is complicated and difficult to understand or maintain when such conditional code is included "inline" with the other, non conditional code.

One way to make this cleaner and clearer is to put conditional code outside the function, and choose among alternatives in a clearly separated function.

For example, let's say the concept is to get columns. Know that is different for each OS case, start by declaring a function to get columns:

```
int GetColumns();
```

Now, DEFINE the function depending on the operating system:

```
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS

int GetColumns()
{
 int cols(0);
 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
 cols = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;

 return cols;
}

#else
#ifdef TIOCGSIZE
int GetColumns()
{
  int cols;
  struct ttysize ts;
  ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGSIZE, &ts);
  cols = ts.ts_cols;
  return cols;
}
#elif defined( TIOCGWINSZ )
int GetColumns()
{
  int cols;
  struct winsize ts;
  ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ts);
  cols = ts.ws_col;
  return cols;
}
#endif // elif

#endif // else to OS_WINDOWS
```

I have not reviewed all of your code within these blocks, but the point here is to separate these concepts to make the code clearer, cleaner and easier to use.

In your main function you now only need:

```
int cols = GetColumns();
```

What this does is acknowledge that you need a way to get columns, and that's it. It clearly separates the complications of getting the columns from the code that calls for it.

Now, the side effects of the various conditional code no longer corrupts the function you're writing. If there are complications, they are now isolated with the body of the various versions of GetColumns. The function "wraps" the issues of local variables, differences in function calls, inside the function.

This also makes it usable from elsewhere in the program without repeating conditional code.

Comment: Although doing it this way, I would drop the `cols` variable entirely from the `GetColumns` and just directly return whatever is used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks everyone. I changed a few more things and now it's working for me:

```
        unsigned get_terminal_cols()
        {
            unsigned c = -1;
            #ifdef _WIN32
                CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
                GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
                c = csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left - 3;
            #else
                struct winsize w;
                ioctl(STDOUT_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
                c = w.ws_col -3;
            #endif // _WIN32
            return c;
        }
```